# Postback url in google wallet PHP integration

Tags: php, laravel-4, android-pay

It is very frustrating. I have everything in place for google wallet, I am working in laravel4. I have a postback url set in sandbox. Below are the steps for google wallet which I could get done,
1. Send jwt value like this `google.payments.inapp.buy({
        jwt: jwt_value,
        success: function() {console.log('success');},
        failure: function(result) {console.log(result.response.errorType);}
      });`
2. I am sure above code works. Now, I have postback url set in sandbox, I should state that when I tried to save the postback url it gave me an error that there was some technical problem with saving the url and when I went to https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/merchant/settings.html, it shows that the postback url was saved. Now I have a POST method for that url and the error I get is `Unfortunately, we could not confirm your purchase with the merchant's server. Your order has been canceled. Please contact the merchant if this problem continues.` 
I understand that the above error is because I did not send a `200 ok` status with `orderID`. The jwt response looks something like this, 
`[,,"{\"jwt\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJHb29nbGUiLCJyZXF1ZXN0Ijp7Im5hbWUiOiJ0ZXN0aW5nIiwiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiJFZGl0aW5nIFNlcnZpY2UiLCJwcmljZSI6IjQzIiwiY3VycmVuY3lDb2RlIjoiVVNEIiwic2VsbGVyRGF0YSI6IiJ9LCJyZXNwb25zZSI6eyJvcmRlcklkIjoiR1dER19TLmM5OWU2Mjc5LTkzY2YtNGM4Mi05Yzc0LTYyN2FiYzUzZDg0MyJ9LCJ0eXAiOiJnb29nbGUvcGF5bWVudHMvaW5hcHAvaXRlbS92MS9wb3N0YmFjay9idXkiLCJhdWQiOiIxMDQzMTgyNDAzNDkwMzc0MDc3NiIsImlhdCI6MTQxNTAyMjM2NCwiZXhwIjoxNDE1MDIyMzg0fQ.sewVF5sTywArre-Vor2JsSc5FwCME4g4QbX4sKYbsoI\",\"request\":{\"name\":\"testing\",\"description\":\"Editing Service\",\"price\":\"43\",\"currencyCode\":\"USD\",\"sellerData\":\"\"},\"response\":{\"orderId\":\"GWDG_S.c99e6279-93cf-4c82-9c74-627abc53d843\"}}",,,7]`
For a lot of time I researched why I couldn't send the `200 ok` status but now I see that the postback url won't return to the saved url. I added a laravel log::info statement at the start of controller function. Anybody has any idea where I am going on the wrong track. Thanks in advance. FYI I have a POST method for postback url.

Comment: Are you saying Google doesn't send a request to your postback url? Can you POST to your postback url (mock it) with the JWT sample above and see what happens? Hth...

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the reply. My problem was I was using Laravel's `before('auth')` function on the postback url in my system, so even though Google was sending the postback I wasn't able to receive it as my system was trying to authenticate the user, apparently google wallet will just log the user out of application even for "inapp" methods. Hence once the Payment was successful I had to login the user manually with `Auth::login()`.